# Converting TCHAR to a char* for strstr function

Tags: c++, c, qt

```
    char skype[6] = "Skype";
    HWND firstwindow = FindWindowEx(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    HWND window = firstwindow;
    TCHAR windowtext[MAX_PATH]; //search term

    //We need to get the console title in case we
    //accidentally match the search word with it
    //instead of the intended target window.
    TCHAR consoletitle[MAX_PATH];
    GetConsoleTitle(consoletitle, MAX_PATH);

    while(true){
        //Check window title for a match
        GetWindowText(window, windowtext, MAX_PATH);
        if (strstr(windowtext, skype)!=NULL && strcmp(windowtext, consoletitle)!=0) break; //search for program
            //Get next window
            window = FindWindowEx(NULL, window, NULL, NULL);
        if(window == NULL || window == firstwindow){
            printf("Window not found.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    } //end while
```

```
Error: cannot convert 'TCHAR* {aka wchar_t*}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'char* strstr(const char*, const char*)'
```

Problem occurs at this line:

```
if (strstr(windowtext, skype)!=NULL && strcmp(windowtext, consoletitle)!=0) break; //search for program
```

I don't have a problem when I run the same program in cygwin mingw32gcc compiler. Is this a issue with me using QT mingw32gcc compiler? I have included `<windows.h>` at the very beginning so that's not the issue.

Edit: Ok So I've added `<tchar.h>` and substituted
    if (_tcsstr(windowtext, skype)!=NULL && _tcscmp(windowtext, consoletitle)!=0) break;

But the problem still persists:  Error: cannot convert 'TCHAR* {aka wchar_t*}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'char* strstr(const char*, const char*)'

Comment: Please read this first:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/dd374131(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Unless you plan on supporting Windows 9x, get rid of the TCHARs and use wide strings for interacting with the API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of converting to `char *` to use in `strstr`, you should use the `TCHAR`-equivalent, `_tcsstr`; it'll compile to the correct call to either `strstr` or `wcsstr`.

Comment: Both operands need to be the same type though, so he would have to replace `char skype[6] = "Skype";` with `TCHAR skype[] = _T("Skype");`.   Although in this day and age just using `wchar_t` seems simpler.

Answer (score 0):

To use unicode in you code you need to define `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` preprocessor macros before compiling you code, so add this command line arguments to you compiling command:

```
-DUNICODE -D_UNICODE
```

for more you can read this:
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/90069